# How can i take snapshot of command prompt window in full screen mode

Tags: screenshot, fullscreen, cmd, printscreen

I need to take snapshot if command prompt window running in full screen mode.

I had tried it using PrintScreen,Ctrl+PrintScreen, Ctrl+Alt+PrintScreen button(s) but nothing seems to work

Also are there any reasons that the print screen button does not work in full screen commandprompt mode?  After all, it does for all windows under normal conditions.

Abdul Khaliq

Comment: So just to understand, you're running windows command prompt in full screen mode, you hit the print screen key, then you go into paint and paste, and it does not work?

Comment: If the command prompt window is in text-mode, Print-Screen will copy the text of what is displayed in the window to the Clipboard, not an image. (At least that appears to be the default behavior in Windows XP.)

Comment: agreed but i need to capture the screen shot of it. Also any reasons why print screen is behaving like this in full screen mode.

Comment: well can u plz explain reason why print screen is behaving like this in full screen mode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In full screen mode all you have is text. There is no graphical `rendering' as such. If you can capture the text, it is enough ... though you can always reconstruct a png image later from the text (if you really have to get an image out of it).

Comment: ok can u explain why there is no graphical rendering in full screen mode of cmd or how does cmd works in full screen mode.

Comment: I guess instead of using the graphical mode, the display switches to text mode, where the BIOS renders the display and not OS GUI. So even the OS has to send "characters" to be displayed, not "bitmapped image". So, the OS sends character 'A' to BIOS to print, and BIOS prints it (using its own font). In graphical mode, the OS sends the 'bitmap of A' to the screen, and hence you can take a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use an external screen shot software?

There's many, e.g. [greenshot](http://greenshot.sourceforge.net/), which is free (is in speech and beer :-)).

Comment: well actually i need to do it programatically

Answer (score 0):

did you try alt + print screen?

Answer (score 0):

Click any window except the command window and then hit PrtScrn.

Comment: how can i click on any window when i am in full screen mode of command prompt

Answer (score 0):

First off all open cmd in full screen mode then click on print screen button after that open paint brush and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> (past) you can save it in any where, where ever you want (file type should be .png).

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to find any of these replies that work, and I can't install unapproved software do to IT policies. Here is what I did:

Right click inside command window. Hit select all. Right click outside of window (on top bar close to the maximize minimize controls. Select edit; select copy. Open a notepad window and paste. The advantage here is you have text that can be copied and pasted back into a command window later. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>     //select all
2. press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>      // copy all text
3. write   notepad mytext.txt + press entet    // open notepad
4. press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>       //paste in text in notepad
5. press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>         // Save file
6. press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>          // Close notepad.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the top bar of the command prompt (no buttons, just the empty top bit) and while you hold, enter in your screenshot short cut. It will cut to the screenshot and you can then select whatever you want to capture.

Comment: didn't work like that back in 2009, but a valid answer for 2023. Btw: `ALT`-`Print` manages to take a screenshot (image, not text), even in full-screen mode.